# Http compression showing garbled response with orchard cms

Tags: sql-server-ce, orchardcms, iis-8.5, http-compression, orchardcms-1.10

I am using Win 2012 and IIS 8.5 with Orchard CMS 1.10.1.  The DB is SQL CE.  I am trying to enable http compression and keep intermittently getting a strange response after enabling dynamic content compression through IIS.

I added this line in the web.config of the orchard application to enable http compression:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
```

Here is what the page displays sometimes:

[image]

When I am not getting this strange browser response (which happens in all browsers), the page loads fine and and even tests positive for gzip encryption on this site: https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/

Comment: Can you check if output cache module is enabled? if yes, then try to disable it, I faced same problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false"
```

Reason why you get garbled responses has to do with **Orchard.OutputCache** module caching response that is already gzipped and then when it serves that cache IIS will gzip that response once again and browsers don't do double decompression.

That flag is meant for IIS output caching which you are not using as Orchard has superior implementation. So even with that flag turned off it will still do compression before output caching.

Comment: Or you can remove that flag all-together as false is default value for it.